# Firebase User registeration

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am fairly new at android app development, I am trying to make an activity from where users can sign up into the database, this is the code

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextInputLayout mEmail, mPassword;
    Button mRegisterButton;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    Button loginAccountButton;
    ProgressDialog progressDialogue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.password);
        mEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.email);
        loginAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginalready);
        mRegisterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
        progressDialogue = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        loginAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,login.class));
            }
        });

        mRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                registeruser();
            }

            private void registeruser() {
                String email = mEmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
                progressDialogue.setMessage("Please wait");
                progressDialogue.show();
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    progressDialogue.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"You're now registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                                else{
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Something went horribly wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

            }
        });



}}
```

All the classes are imported properly and there seems to be no way around it, the code was working a few hours ago but now it just won't budge every time I try and run the code it gives me the Toast *something went horribly wrong*

```
this is the activity_register.xml

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="EMAIL" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email"
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="PASSWORD" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/registerButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="REGISTER"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="280dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginalready"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="login"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:text="login?"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.051" />
```

Comment: Can you paste your log? May be helpful to identify

Comment: toast task.error

Comment: check your internet connection

Comment: internet connection seems to be working fine, I am trying toast task.error right now @AdityaVyas-Lakhan

Comment: there is nothing related to internet connection @Sahil post your xml containing your 'TextInputLayout'.in tthis case you are getting nullpointer errr

Comment: posted the xml @SaurabhBhandari can you also tell me how to use toast task.error as Divyesh pointed out I don't know the first thing about it.

Comment: use Toast.makeText(activity, "Authentication failed:" +      
        task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: @Sahil i post my answer try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `android:id=""` to your `EditText` instead of the `TextInputLayout` as follows

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/displayName"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:hint="EMAIL" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:hint="PASSWORD" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

In Your Java File create Objects Of `EdiText` instead of `TextInputLayout` and get values as follows.

```
EdiText mEmail, mPassword;

    mPassword = (EdiText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mEmail = (EdiText) findViewById(R.id.email);
```

Values Are entered by user in `EditText` not in `TextInputLayout` so You have to get values from the EditText

I hope its work for You! Thanks